# PHPUnit whitelist vs test suite code coverage

Tags: php, phpunit

I currently have a phpunit.xml file that looks like this:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Some questions I have:

Am I right to assume that in my `<testsuite>` the `<directory suffix="Test.php">tests` checks for file that correspond to Test*.php in that directory?

I currently have a **.php** file inside my **src** folder with some HTML in it. PHPUnit picks up on this file and dumps the entire content of it as output when running my unit tests. I guess this is because of my whitelist  setting with the `processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist`.

I guess this looks over all the files with .php extension and checks whether they have been tested or not.

I can simply change the whitelist to my tests directory and this solves the problem but I guess this makes my CodeCoverage reports unable to see which classes have not been tested yet?

What am I to do here when I still want to have simply .php files inside my project that I want to include somewhere? Do I write something in my phpunit.xml file to ignore these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude that file (and any other non-testable files) with the following:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>/path/to/your_html_file.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

In answer to your first question, the Test.php is the suffix so it looks for *Test.php.